# Share MAMP in virtual pc as well

Tags: vmware-fusion, localhost, mamp

I have a MAMP installation on my mac, and I use vmware fusion to run a virtual windows installation. I was wondering if there's a way to share the localhost i have in mac with the vmware windows installation?